# PyTorch gradient calculation gives unexpected results

Tags: python, pytorch, gradient, matrix-multiplication, autograd

The following code is intended to explain how the PyTorch gradient calculation works, and it should, IMO return the weights matrix, but it doesn't:

```
# the code calculates T x W + B ---> K1
# compute the mean of K1 --> km
# compute the gradient of km relative to T
#
import torch
torch.manual_seed(0)
t = torch.rand(2,3)
w = torch.rand(3,4)
b = torch.rand(1,4)
#
k1 = torch.mm(t, w) + b
#
#torch.set_grad_enabled(True)
print('k1_grad_fn ',k1.grad_fn)
#
print('t grad ',t.grad)
#
#
km = k1.mean()
km.requires_grad_(True)
print('k1 mean=',km)
km.backward()
print('t grad ',t.grad)
print('k1 grad ',k1.grad_fn)
```

The results are:

````
t grad  None
k1 mean= tensor(1.0396, requires_grad=True)
t grad  None
k1 grad  None```
````

Answer (score 0):

It's not strange, it is expected as [indicated by Autograd Mechanics in PyTorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/autograd.html):

> Backward computation is never performed in the subgraphs, where all
>   Tensors didn’t require gradients.

Setting `km.required_grad_(True)` creates a subgraph (with only single operation being a mean of `k1` tensor) so you get `k1_mean.grad`. Please notice `k1 grad` would also be `None` in this case as it doesn't require gradient.

By default `tensor` has `required_grad` set to `False` so the graph doesn't have to perform unnecessary operations. To get your desired behaviour change your `t` to:

```
t = torch.rand((2, 3), requires_grad=True)
```

(each tensor function has `requires_grad` argument). This gives you, as you probably expected:

```
k1_grad_fn  <AddBackward0 object at 0x7fe3454d6100>
t grad  None
k1 mean= tensor(1.0396, grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>)
t grad  tensor([[0.3093, 0.1177, 0.2888],
        [0.3093, 0.1177, 0.2888]])
k1 grad  <AddBackward0 object at 0x7fe3454d6100>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Still, the output is not what I expected to see. I'd be grateful for help about the correct mathematical solution.

Comment: It is mathematically correct, what do you mean? `tensor.mean()` returns scalar as it should, `k1` `grad_fn` is `Addbackward` as expected as well, `k1` has no `grad` as given in the answer, `w` and `b` would need `require_grad` argument just like `t` but those were not included in the output.  Please make your question more specific if I still miss the point or specify which part exactly you are after but is not explained in-depth enough.

Comment: my expectation (probably mistaken) was to see the weight matrix in the output because I am doing the derivative of T x W with respect to t. The output is instead a 2x4 matrix which I would like to calculate manually for verification

Comment: You do it with respect to `t` only when you specify `requires_grad` like above. And `.grad` is a matrix as you can see in the answer, it's the same shape, `2x3` as you originally created. How else could PyTorch know `w.r.t.` to what you are performing derivative? If PyTorch kept __every gradient of every operation__ as `grad` attribute it would be wasteful as it's usually not needed and only occupies memory.

Comment: Thanks again. I finally figured that out. https://documentcloud.adobe.com/link/track?uri=urn%3Aaaid%3Ascds%3AUS%3Abbe03c0e-56b4-417a-ac31-cd1351785e20

Comment: @josephpareti glad I could help, it's great you checked and verified PyTorch's results instead of following blindly, nice notes.